# ECS Integration with AppDynamics Issue

Tags: openshift, amazon-ecs, appdynamics

Currently, I got a task about integrating ECS openshift with AppDynamics.
Here is my  situation, I   have Integrated my project with  AppDynamics . I can’t see my project  on   appDynamics   Dashboard, but I can see it on the Tier and node. i have checked the router for openshift,it’s not available ，so i want to ask you guys if it is the reason why i can not see my project  on the AppDynamics  Dashboard ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Nodes are showing under "Tiers & Nodes" this means that the Agents are reporting to the AppDynamics Controller.

If however there is nothing shown in the Application (or Tier, or Node) Dashboards this means that there are no registered Business Transactions relating to that Application (or Tier, or Node).

Dashboards (or flow maps, more accurately) generally show a view of registered Business Transactions (not simply of entities which are known to the Controller).

Have a look at the docs for an explanation of what a Business Transaction is and how these can be configured should none be detected OOTB:

- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.2/en/application-monitoring/configure-instrumentation/transaction-detection-rules
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.2/en/application-monitoring/business-transactions

Comment: it is very nice of you ,Thanks for your great help.